# Deploying C # Application

Tags: c#

First of all, sorry if my question seems stupid but i really need help on that. I have just released my C# Application. I have the exe in the release folder. In my application i made use of references such as WMPLib to play videos in an integrated multimedia player. When the application is in the release folder it works fine, but when i copy the exe only on the desktop, i get an error that the lib reference was not found. so my question is how can i make my exe find the libraries no matter where they are on the computer? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: You can't just copy the exe, you need all the files in the build output directory.

Comment: Consider using an MSI package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through these links first:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173084(v=vs.80).aspx

[How do I install/deploy/build my Visual C# application so it's available to all users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425207/how-do-i-install-deploy-build-my-visual-c-sharp-application-so-its-available-to)