# How to install exe to multiple users

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, windows-installer, desktop-application

I developed an application using .Net C# language. I have one windows form application. Is it possible to upload these setup files to all users at once?

Comment: How are the other users connected ? Is there a server ? All the local users of the machine ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install/deploy/build my Visual C# application so it's available to all users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425207/how-do-i-install-deploy-build-my-visual-c-sharp-application-so-its-available-to)

Comment: I created users with Active Directory